# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pdone.BaseUser' doesn't exist

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-user-bundle, sonata, symfony-2.7

I'm using FOSUserBundle 1.3.x-dev from within [SonataUserBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/index.html). I have follow every step on [UserBundle installation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html) to install and configure all. This is what I have at entities:

```
#src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

#src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Entity/Group.php

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup as BaseGroup;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Group extends BaseGroup
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

This is how configuration looks like:

```
#FOSUserBundle
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User

    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager

    from_email:
        address:        noreply@pdi.com
        sender_name:    Mail Service

doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8

                logging: true
                profiling: true
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
          default:
            #I have tried here using mappings and without it - same issue
            mappings:
                FOSUserBundle: ~
                ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                SonataUserBundle: ~
            auto_mapping: true
            filters:
                softdeleteable:
                  class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                  enabled: false
```

This is a piece of `AppKernel.php`:

```
...
new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),
...
```

This is what I have at `composer.json`  file:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.x-dev",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^2.2",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    ...
    "leaseweb/memcache-bundle": "*"
}
```

I print the error in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login.html.twig` as follow:

```
{{ error|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
```

Every time I try to login I got a message like this:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS
>   password7, t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, 
>   t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.created_at AS created_at17, t0.updated_at AS updated_at18, t0.date_of_birth AS date_of_birth19, t0.firstname AS firstname20, t0.
>   lastname AS lastname21, t0.website AS website22, t0.biography AS biography23, t0.gender AS gender24, t0.locale AS locale25, t0.timezone AS timezone26, t0.phone AS phone27, t0.facebook_uid AS facebook_uid28, t0.facebook_name AS 
>   facebook_name29, t0.facebook_data AS facebook_data30, t0.twitter_uid AS twitter_uid31, t0.twitter_name AS twitter_name32, t0.twitter_data AS twitter_data33, t0.gplus_uid AS gplus_uid34, t0.gplus_name AS gplus_name35, t0.gplus_data AS 
>   gplus_data36, t0.token AS token37, t0.two_step_code AS two_step_code38 FROM BaseUser t0 WHERE t0.username_canonical = ? LIMIT 1' with params ["admin"]: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pdone.BaseUser' doesn't exist

Why is that? Is this a FOSUserBundle problem or a SonataUserBundle issue? Can any give me some advice around this?

**EDIT**

I have performed another test by running the commands below:

```
# php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

# php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force
Dropping database schema...
Database schema dropped successfully!

# php app/console doctrine:schema:create
ATTENTION: This operation should not be executed in a production environment.

Creating database schema...
Database schema created successfully!
```

And again no success, same issue! At all test I clear first the cache

**EDIT 2**

I've run `doctrine:mapping:info` and I got this output, why?

```
Found 18 mapped entities:
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Entity\Group
[OK]   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup
[OK]   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser
[OK]   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
[OK]   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
[OK]   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Representative
[OK]   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Media
[OK]   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Brand
[OK]   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\TerritoryBrand
[OK]   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Email
[OK]   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Company
[OK]   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Action
[OK]   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Message
[OK]   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Territory
[OK]   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\TargetBrand
[OK]   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Event
[OK]   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is very explicit, the table `BaseUser` doesn't exist.

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pdone.BaseUser' doesn't
>   exist

Moreover, please check the [`FOSUserBundle User entity`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) class.
Some annotations (`@ORM\Entity` and `@ORM\Table(name="...")`) are missing.

**For example**

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
     */
    class User extends BaseUser
    {
```

Make sure to generate the database tables with the command

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the [Sonata reference](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html), did you tried to add this code in your `config.yml` ?

```
# Enable Doctrine to map the provided entities
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    FOSUserBundle: ~
                    ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
```

Comment: That not fix my issue, I did what you told me and issue still

Comment: @ReynierPM I fixed an issue in my command `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`. Don't forget to add `--force`. You have the same issue ?

Comment: Yes, there is no other way to run the command other than adding `--force` and yes I added and nothing the same issue

Comment: I've tried this one too, same issue, I have added this to OP

Answer (score 0):

If the command `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` shows nothing your Entity are not mapped.

My first guess is that you need to add auto_mapping in config.yml instead of the Sonata config documentation, this way your Entity will be mapped automatically.

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
```

Also check in your your`app/AppKernel.php` that you have the SonataUserBundle extending FOSUserBundle :

```
new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle')
```

Comment: By running the console command I got this `Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.` and yes I have `auto_mapping:true`  at `config.yml` but same issue